# How can I use a 'const' value as a type?

Tags: typescript

```
const X = "x";
let a:"x"; // This is allowed
let b:X;   // This is not allowed
```

Is there any way I can convince typescript to allow me to use line 3 above? I will use that string for checks etc in many places, and it would be nice to use a constant value as a type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After declaring the `X`, then extract its type with `typeof`, and use that type elsewhere:

```
const x = "x";
type xType = typeof x;

let b: xType;
// OK:
b = 'x';
// Error:
b = 'y'
```

Because `x` is a `const`, the type is inferred to be the literal `'x'` assigned to it. (If you used `let`, you'd need to type annotate it, either with `let x: 'x' = 'x';` or `let x = 'x' as const`)

Comment: TS did not like "as const" (what version accepts that?), but `b: typeof X` works great! Thanks!

Comment: It's supported in TS 3.4+. `typeof X` alone won't be enough, because then `x` will be typed as a string, not as *just* the string `'x'`. Without `as const`, you can type annotate `x`, though it's repetitive for long strings: `const x: 'x' = 'x';

Comment: In this specific case you can skip `as const`. Typescript infers literal type for constants.  [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYewdgzgLgBAHjAvDARHFBuAsAKCgTwAcBTeAFSNOQJJADN5sdcAbY2AIwC5zKmB6fjADyAaS64OSGAHI4MgUICiAJxUgVEnFOQz8MoA)